# Run docker run command as npm script

Tags: docker, npm

I have the following command that runs when run by itself (Output: Hello):

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name fetch_html -v ${pwd}:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.4-cli php 
Hello
```

However, I want to run it as a npm script as it's a little tedious writing the whole thing out every time:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "fetch_html": "docker run -it --rm --name fetch_html -v ${pwd}:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.4-cli php scripts/fetch_html/cli.php"
  },
  ...
```

Then:

```
$ npm run fetch_html
```

But it gives me the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: create ${pwd}: "${pwd}" includes
> invalid characters for a local volume name, only
> "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a
> host directory, use absolute path.

I've tried to change it to $(pwd) as I recall Windows and Linux having different syntax here(?). The host machine is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Windows 10 CMD interpreter, try this:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "fetch_html": "docker run -it --rm --name fetch_html -v %cd%\\:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.4-cli php scripts/fetch_html/cli.php"
  },
  ...
```